# How does c++ handle ">>" operation for ifstream and char arrays?

Tags: c++, linux

if I do something like this

```
ifstream stat_stream("filepath",ios_base::in);
char pid[128];
stat_stream >> pid;
```

is c++ going to do any implicit conversions of my char[] (to a std::string say) or will it leave it as is?

Edit: For clarity, I want to ensure that this is as asynchronous signal safe as it is possible to be when file io is necessary.  I really only meant the implicit conversions as an example of an operation that would be unacceptable.

Comment: Why would you expect an `std::string` to be created? It's not like `pid` (or any variable) could change type.

Comment: [Why don't you use `get()` instead](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)?

Comment: `>>` is an overloaded operator. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3e%3e/). The type of your variable will not change

Comment: I appreciate you inputs. But I am aware of how >> works on the surface level. I just need to ensure that data is being loaded into that char[] in an equivalent manner to a strcpy, without any voodoo in between.

Comment: How the overloaded `>>` operator is implemented is left to the implementation. It may choose to use `std::string`, implicit conversions, fireworks, or black magic internally. This choice doesn't have any observable consequences though.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not implicitly change your char[] to a std::string. You can tell the type by doing: `cout<<typeid(pid).name()<<endl;`

Hope this help.